# MongoDB Amazon Web Service - Do I actually have it installed?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, ssh

I really want to use mongoDB as my server backend for my android application/ web app that im hosting on the cloud. I ( think ) I installed it on my instance but Im confused as when I run my app its not showing up.

I ssh'd into my EC2 instance ( I am running Elastic Beanstalk on ssh) and I installed mongoDb and created all my tables and when I exit and ssh back into it the same tables are there however after reading up on it, I think the process is a little more complicated than that and more expensive.

Can anyone tell me if what I did was correct and if there actually a way to get mongoDb for free like this on Elastic Beanstalk? Its for my Computer Science masters.

EDIT:
I have now used Cloud Formation and installed mongo DB but now have no idea how to deploy my app without elastic beanstalk as my app runs on apache.

Thank you

Comment: I would suggest looking into mlab.com if you want MongoDB as a managed service, similar to how Elastic Beanstalk is a managed service for your web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, keypoints to keep in mind:

1. When you SSH to your Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instances you can see a big message that says that any change that you make directly to your EC2 instances won't be saved anywhere. What I mean, you don't make **ANY** changes in your EC2s if you are using Elastic Beanstalk.
2. AWS has a [MongoDB on the AWS Cloud: Quick Start Reference Deployment Guide](https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/mongodb/latest/doc/MongoDB_on_the_AWS_Cloud.pdf). This document guides you through the process of installing MongoDB (includes a nice CloudFormation template -and it takes only about 15 mins to be ready-)

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.